# Repeating custom directive to attach to array property for input

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-directive

I have created a plunkr. Where I need to get the custom directive repeating . However what I need is when i click the check button then all the inputs should be populated inside the slides array in `presentation-controller` and then I can work with that array.

The problem is the directive is actually adding inputs. When I click the check button, all the inputs should be populated inside the presentation-controller's `$scope.slides[]` array.

[Repeating directive attaching to controller array property](http://plnkr.co/edit/OuEsmkG5e0ATsoI6HqmH?p=preview)

Comment: Looks like the Plunkr has been deleted, so this question is no longer understandable for future readers. We like questions to be as self-contained as possible anyway, so a Plunkr on its own is not sufficient here.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is on the view template **slide-input.html**, here you write  `ng-bind="slides[0]"` and in presentation-controller you write `$scope.slides= ["hello"]` , when you click plus icon, adding  a new directive ,`slides[0]` always displayed you '**hello**'